# Low CPU Usage and Memory Errors in PySpark Job on Dataproc Cluster

Tags: python, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

### Question

I'm running a PySpark job on a Dataproc cluster, and I'm facing two issues: the CPU usage is consistently low (5%-10%), and when I attempt to parse the entire dataset at once, I encounter memory errors. The cluster consists of 8 c2-standard-8 machines with 8 cores and 32GB of RAM each (1 master, 7 workers).

---

This is the code I use for creating the sparkSession

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from utils import load_constant

PARTITION_SIZE = 168


def get_spark_config(app_name: str, environment: str) -> SparkConf:
    conf = (
        SparkConf()
        .setAppName(app_name)
        .setMaster("yarn")
        .set(
            "spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.warehouse.dir",
            load_constant("WAREHOUSE_DIR", environment),
        )
        .set("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
        .set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
        .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
        .set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
        .set("spark.executor.instances", "56")
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "4G")
        .set("spark.driver.memory", "20G")
        .set("spark.executor.cores", "1")
        .set("spark.driver.cores", "8")
        .set("spark.default.parallelism", f"{PARTITION_SIZE}")
        .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", f"{PARTITION_SIZE}")
    )

    return conf


def get_spark_session(
    timestamp: str, workflow_id: str, step_name: str, job_type: str, environment: str
) -> SparkSession:
    """return sparksession for specific job_type"""

    if "spark" in locals():
        spark.stop()  # noqa: F821

    app_name = f"{step_name}_{timestamp}_{workflow_id}"
    if job_type == "local_job":
        return (
            SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name)
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
            .config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
            .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            .getOrCreate()
        )
    if job_type == "delta_job":
        return (
            SparkSession.builder.config(conf=get_spark_config(app_name, environment))
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate()
        )
    raise ValueError(f"job_type: {job_type} unsupported. Should be delta_job or local_job")
```

---

This is the code that is giving me problems. It's a sparknlp pipeline that is splitting into sentences ~22k documents (the delta table size is ~1.4GB) and I'm quite sure this could be much faster.

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from sparknlp.base import DocumentAssembler
from sparknlp.annotator import SentenceDetectorDLModel, Tokenizer, Normalizer

# Import custom functions and classes
from base_step import BaseStep
from utils import BATCH_SIZE


class SplitSentences(BaseStep):
    def __init__(
        self,
        timestamp: str,
        workflow_id: str,
        step_name: str,
        environment: str,
        training: bool = False,
    ):
        super().__init__(
            timestamp,
            workflow_id,
            step_name,
            job_type="delta_job",
            environment=environment,
            training=training,
        )

        self.pipeline = self.create_nlp_pipeline()

    def create_nlp_pipeline(self) -> Pipeline:
        """Create NLP processing pipeline with different stages."""
        document_assembler = (
            DocumentAssembler().setInputCol("processed_text").setOutputCol("document")
        )

        sentence_detector = (
            SentenceDetectorDLModel.pretrained("sentence_detector_dl", "en")
            .setInputCols(["document"])
            .setOutputCol("sentences")
        )

        tokenizer = Tokenizer().setInputCols(["sentences"]).setOutputCol("tokens")

        normalizer = (
            Normalizer()
            .setInputCols(["tokens"])
            .setOutputCol("tokens")
            .setCleanupPatterns(["""[^\w\d\s]"""])
            .setLowercase(True)
            .setMinLength(3)
        )

        pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[document_assembler, sentence_detector, tokenizer, normalizer])
        return pipeline

    def apply_pipeline(self, df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
        """Apply the NLP pipeline on the 'text' column and return the output DataFrame."""
        return self.pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)

    def run(self, args) -> DataFrame:
        """Run the cleaning and translation pipelines."""

        remaining_df = (
            self.load_table(
                database_name="silver", table_name="processed_document", load_partition=True
            )
            .select("document_id", "processed_text")
            .dropDuplicates(["document_id"])
        )

        total_rows = remaining_df.select("document_id").count()
        num_of_batches = total_rows // BATCH_SIZE

        for i in range(num_of_batches):
            self.logger.info(f"Parsing batch {i+1}/{num_of_batches}")
            batch_df = remaining_df.limit(BATCH_SIZE)
            remaining_df = remaining_df.subtract(batch_df)

            output_df = self.apply_pipeline(batch_df).select("document_id", "sentences", "tokens")
            self.logger.info("NLP Pipeline completed")

            self.save_table(output_df, database_name="silver", table_name="tokenized_document")
            self.logger.info("Saved")
            output_df.unpersist()
```

The sparkSession is created in the constructor of `BaseStep`, `BATCH_SIZE` is 2000 and I had to add this, as I was having `bad alloc` and memory errors when I tried to parse the entire dataset.
These are `load_table` and `save_table` method for completition

```py
def load_table(
        self,
        database_name: str,
        table_name: str,
        load_partition: bool = False,
        partition_size: int = PARTITION_SIZE,
    ):
        """Loads a DF from a table in metastore"""
        table_format = "parquet" if self.training else "delta"
        table_path = f"{self.get_constant('WAREHOUSE_DIR')}/{database_name}.db/{table_name}"

        output_df = self.spark_session.read.format(table_format).load(table_path)
        if load_partition:
            output_df = output_df.filter(output_df[self.created_date_column] == self.timestamp)

        return output_df.repartition(partition_size, self.created_date_column)

def save_table(self, output_df, database_name: str, table_name: str):
        """Loads a DF from a table in metastore"""
        table_format = "parquet" if self.training else "delta"
        table_path = f"{self.get_constant('WAREHOUSE_DIR')}/{database_name}.db/{table_name}"

        output_df = output_df.withColumn(self.created_date_column, lit(self.timestamp))

        return (
            output_df.repartition(PARTITION_SIZE, self.created_date_column)
            .write.mode("append")
            .format(table_format)
            .partitionBy(self.created_date_column)
            .save(table_path)
        )
```

At the moment, I'm using `created_date` as partition but I think it's not the wisest choise as I have the same value for all the rows each time I run this job.

---

**Specific Questions:**

- Why is my Pyspark job using such low CPU power?
- Why am I getting memory errors when attempting to parse the whole dataset at once?
- Can I optimize my SparkNLP pipeline for better performance?

**Additional Context:** I don't have (yet) access to Yarn ResourceManager UI but I'm trying to get it, so I can check if all the workers are running/doing something or not.

Comment: Could you add the error message about memory? It will help figure out whether it is driver or executor.

Comment: I was able to find my problem. I had a very small amount of documents (~1k) that had 1m+ characters. Those were causing the worker to crash! I split those into manageable blocks (~200k characters each) and now it's working like a charm, without the need of the batching processing either